# mocking css modules in 'Create React App app'

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, create-react-app, css-loader

I have an app build on top of **Create React App** (CRA), using **css modules**.
When I test my components with Enzyme, I see that the classes are all 'undefined'.

I saw 1 way to fix it, is using identity-obj-proxy and adding "moduleNameMapper" entry under "jest" in my package.json, in order to resolve css imports.
Since i'm using CRA, these entry in package.json is not allowed.

**what's the best approach for testing react components using CRA and css modules ? do I have to eject ?**

Comment: What version of `react-scripts` are you using ?

Comment: `react-script` is 1.1.1

Comment: `identity-obj-proxy` is included with create-react-app now.